# Why the controller's class method aren't get called when the app become active from background?

Tags: ios, background, viewdidload, viewdidappear

when I share something with my app, it get called by 
`-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{`to get the content shared with it. After that, i need to present Modally a content in the first controller of the app, but if call from the `appDelegate`the function `[self.library showContent:item];`where's library is the main controller on the app, it doesn't called the class method like `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` of the main controller but only the `applicationDidBecomeActive` from `appDelegate`, and i can't run a`presentModalViewController` from the `showContent` method, because it's view isn't on screen yet.

short version: why when app comes from `applicationDidBecomeActive` it doesn't call first controller's class method like `viewDidAppear` ? How con i call in the main controller a `presentModalViewController` if I didn't know when the main controller is on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that U r mixing up the `UIViewController` Lifecycle and application lifecycle, this two are different.

Brief tip: take your code from `ViewDidAppear`out to external method and try to invoke this method somewhere from `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

For application lifecycle, see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) link.

For `UIViewController` lifecycle see [this](http://www.learnprogrammingios.com/2013/10/viewcontroller-lifecycle.html) link.

Hope that could help.

Comment: "Brief tip: take your code from ViewDidAppearout to external method and try to invoke this method somewhere from applicationDidBecomeActive." Ok, but i need to know that when i call this function my controller (the old one) is on screen, to finally create a new modal one on it.

Comment: yeah but if I try to instantiate a presentmodalview on it on Log I see " whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Answer (score 0):

When the application becomes active from the background it opens with the view it has in the front when it was put in the background. To present a view controller when you share something with your app using a url scheme, you have to tell your app to do so in your handle open url method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation{
         /* put code to get the data you want to extract
         from the url scheme here */
         // and then load the view
         MyController *v = [[MyController alloc] init]; 
         [self loadThisController:v];//replace with any method you want to use to load this.
}
```

Comment: I know, but i don't want to replace the old controller with the new one. The new one has to be a modal controller in the old one, so i need to finish load the old one and load in it a presentModalViewController.

Comment: @Nikos M. I think that your answer mislead.
When u reload the viewController U deal with some side effect that u not necessarily wants such as network call, I/O and more.